# How to call pointer member function inside a class definition?

Tags: c++, pointers

How do I call a pointer member function within a class definition?
My code:

```
//Myclass.h

struct Booking{
  int src;
  int dest;
  int pos;
};

class MyClass{
public:
    void ExecutePlan();
private:
    struct FlightPlan{
      string name;
      vector<Booking> bookings
    };

    typedef FlightPlan FP;
    FP firstplan;
    FP secondplan;
    void FirstPlan(Booking& book);
    void SecondPlan(Booking& book);
    void Execute(FP& fplan, void (MyClass::*mptr)(Booking& book));
};

// Myclass.cpp
void MyClass::FirstPlan(Booking& book){
// do something with booking
}

void MyClass::SecondPlan(Booking& book){
// do something with booking
}

void MyClass::Execute(FP& fplan, void(MyClass::*mptr)(const FlightPlan& fp)){
    for (int i=0; i<.fplan.bookings.size(); i++){
        cout << "Executing Plan: "<< fplan.name << endl;

       // Problematic line ...
        mptr(bookings[i]);   // <----- can't compile with this
    }
}

void MyClass::Execute(){
// is this the correct design to call this member functions ???

   Execute(firstplan, &MyClass::FirstPlan)   
   Execute(secondplan, &MyClass::SecondPlan)   
}
```

How can i structure the Execute Function to receive a member function as a pointer?

Pls: Am a newbie in C++, maybe the design is weird!!

Paul

Comment: You need an instance to call it on, there are many duplicates about how to do it here on SO. I also suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The instance is known since we call from within `MyClass::Execute`.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Even if the instance is known, it needs to be used when calling the member function pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to call pointer member function inside a class definition?

Unlike member names, member pointers aren't implicitly applied to `this`. You have to be explicit:

```
(this->*mptr)(fplan.bookings[i]);
```

> is this the correct design to call this member functions ???

Apart from a few obvious errors (such as missing `;` here and there, saying `const FlightPlan&` where you mean `Booking&` in the definition of `Execute`), the rest of the code looks fine. Specifically

```
Execute(firstplan, &MyClass::FirstPlan)   
Execute(secondplan, &MyClass::SecondPlan)
```

is the correct syntax for obtaining the member-function pointers.

Comment: Am getting syntax error "class MyClass has no member named 'mptr' ??

Comment: @gath: That sounds like you wrote `->` instead of `->*`.

Comment: actually am using ->*, is my Execute function signature correct void MyClass::Execute(FP& fplan, void(MyClass::*mptr)(const FlightPlan& fp))  ?

Comment: it worked. I guess eclipse required me to run a clean up routine

Answer (score 1):

The operator to call a member function pointer is `->*`. Since you want to call it on `this` object, you need to use

```
(this->*mptr)(bookings[i]);
```